# Arabic charactors converting into some special charactors in form submittion (Eg: &#65227;&#65166;)

Tags: database, post, coldfusion, character-encoding, arabic

I am submitting a form which contains some Arabic input text fields. Please check the form below.

```
<form name="formName" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="windows-1256">
    <input type="text" name="arabicField" value="" maxlength="50" id="arabicField">
</form>
```

When dumped the form value, am getting the field value in the dump as 'ﻋﺎﻣ'

When I am trying to insert the form field value into the database, I am getting the error message "**value too large for column "COLUMN_NAME" (actual: 139, maximum: 50)** ".

Please give me an idea to get the form submission value without '&#'.

Comment: It's due to accept-charset="windows-1256".

Comment: It never support Arabic if I remove accept-charset="windows-1256"

Comment: Try changing it to utf-8.